# WPF Combo Box Visible Items Not Updating

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box defined in WPF that is bound to an observable collection of options as shown below.

```
private ObservableCollection<SeriesOption> _SeriesOptions;
        public ObservableCollection<SeriesOption> SeriesOptions
        {
            get { return _SeriesOptions; }
            set { Set<ObservableCollection<SeriesOption>>(() => SeriesOptions, ref _SeriesOptions, value); }
        }
```

This is defined in a custom object of which I have a list of (called ModulePlots), and a "selected" item (called SelectedModulePlot) in my view model. So the items in my combo box should be updated based on which ModulePlot is selected on the UI.

It works as expected when nothing is selected in the combo box. Once I select an option in the combo box for one of the ModulePlots, the number of items in the combo box sticks to the number that was in the combo box when I selected one.

So if I select something when the combo box had 8 items, then select a different ModulePlot that only has 1 item, it has 7 blank items in the combo box.

I have already checked that the number of options is correct when the second ModulePlot is selected, and the items in the combo box do change. It just seems that the number of visible items is not being updated.

Has anyone else seen this issue or something similar? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: There are a lot of details missing, such as how it's setting the SeriesOptions based on SelectedModulePlot, how it's bound to the list, what happens when the selection changes, etc. I have many `ObservableCollection` and multi-threaded ObservableCollections bound to lists and comboboxes, and they always display the correct number of items.

Comment: Some of the details you are asking for. The SeriesOptions are contained in a custom object defined in the ViewModel file. The ViewModel itself has an ObservableCollection of these custom objects. It also has a single object of that type that acts as the "SelectedCustomObject". 

The ComboBox itself is bound to the "SelectedCustomObject.SeriesOptions" object from that Collection.

Comment: So basically you're saying it's like `ViewModel.ModulePlotCollection` and `ViewModel.SelectedModulePlot` with `ViewModel.SelectedModulePlot.SeriesOptionCollection` being what you're bound to?

Comment: Yes, so the SeriesOptionCollection is set on the creation of each ViewModel.ModuleplotCollection entry. The binding itself has not proven to be an issue. When a SeriesOption is not selected, the combobox updates as expected. The issue only arises when you select a SeriesOption. Then it seems that the number of visible items is not being updated on the combobox, but everything else is.